# How can I access/update a column in a document library using a powershell script?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

MyList is a document library with a column called 'name'. I am trying to do this in my Powershell script:

```
$myList= $subWeb.Lists["MyList"]
$items= $myList.Items | sort Title

foreach ($li in $items) {
    Write-Host $li.name # is empty?
}
```

When I look in the interface it clearly shows rows in the MyList library. Why is $li.name empty or how can I get the $li.name property?

Answer (score 0):

```
$myList = $subWeb.Lists["MyList"]
$item s= $myList.Items | sort Title

foreach ($li in $items) {
    Write-Host $li.["Name"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the file name.

It resides in an internal hidden column `FileLeafRef`.

Modify your code as below:

```
$myList = $subWeb.Lists["MyList"]
$items = $myList.Items | sort Title

foreach ($li in $items) {
    Write-Host $li["FileLeafRef"] #should output something like - test.docx
    #to update list item
    $li["FileLeafRef"] = "newFileName.docx"  #change it as per your requirement
    $li["Title"] = "New document title"
    $li.Update();
}
```

Comment: Would be a shame if there were more than one document with that filename and extension or other filetypes than docx in the library, don’t you agree? ;)

Comment: I tried $li["description"] for another column which contains a custom string value and still is empty?

Comment: @Christoffer - true that ;) 
@bierhier - You should ideally use internal column name in PowerShell, check if the name is something like `$li["Description"]`  and also check if the column itself has some value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Library settings->Columns, and find the column and click it.

Then you will find the internal name of the field via **Field** parameter of the URL:
[image]

Then in your PowerShell commands, you need to use the internal name.

A demo for your reference:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue

$SPweb = Get-SPWeb "http://your site url"
$SPlist = $SPweb.Lists["your library"]
$items=$SPlist.Items | sort Title

foreach ($SPitem in $items)
{
    write-host $SPitem["name1"]

}
```

Note: you need to change "name1" to the internal name of your column.